# how can bootstrap's responsive menu appear immediately

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu, icons, width, screen

I'm making a responsive website on bootstrap. I already have a responsive menu but I want the "hamburger"/menu icon to appear when the width of the screen is at 900px. How can I do that? Because it only appears when the screen is at 766px and the menu is already overlapping with the logo.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap you can use [Glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons)

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"</span>
```

You could just add this span to the nav.
You can wrap it with a button or dropdown class to make it do stuff.

You could also use:

```
class="hidden"
```

or

```
class="visible"
```

These allow to control when the icon is visible or hidden.

[Bootstrap Responsive Utilities (hidden, visible, etc)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_responsive_utilities.htm)

If you don't want to use Glyphicons you can use [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/icon/cog/)

Comment: Hi this is what im using

<span class="sr-only ">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

How can I make it appear at a certain size before the menu overlaps the logo?

Answer (score 0):

Or alter the menu and have the nmenu on the top

or reduce the width in % of the div (container) where site-logo is contained in. You cann price this by adding @media (query s to your CSS

or reduce the size of the size of the menu bar by minimizing the mein menu (less menu topics and short names and icons for homepage and contact) and add instead sub menu's

What you mention is a disadvantage of the bootsrap navgar type you used. It has a limited use
   Most of the time its manageble with the tricks mentioned above

chears
JB-Webdev